# Markdown Heading with HTML as text on Github

Tags: github, markdown

When writing my markdown README.md file I want to have the HTML element tag `<p>` as the heading using two ## for a h2 look. but it will not display the tag. Is there a certain form of syntax I need to use in order for it to be displayed as text and not interpreted as an HTML element. Can someone link me to a Github repo as an example.

Code currently using (does not display on Github):

```
## <p>
```

Answer (score 2):

The angle brackets need to be encoded as character entities so that they are not interpreted as Markdown or HTML.

I tested the following [in a gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/MaxLaumeister/14187fdfc2e59e02bf9e) and it works:

```
## &lt;p&gt;
```

---

It also works as inline Markdown on Stack Overflow (click "edit" to see the Markdown source for my post):

### <p>